# WPF App - JumpList 'Close Window' button - how to change behavior

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to modify the behavior of '*Close Window*' button from jump list (to show "*Are you sure*" dialog or minimize a window like in Skype app).

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle `Closing` event for your window:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Closing app", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

and in xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SO_app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SO_app.Converters"
    xmlns:validation="clr-namespace:SO_app.Validation"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closing="Window_Closing"><- here you define the handler
```